# Is it possible to test textures in glsl or cg?

Tags: opengl, textures, glsl, render-to-texture, cg

I am trying to see if my texture coming in to my shader.

I am have the following code so far but I need to know if my texture is coming in to my fragment shader or not.

Is it even possible to test that?

Thanks for the answers already

```
sampler2D activeTex;

float screenwidth = 1024;
float screenheight = 1024;

float x= gl_FragCoord.x/screenwidth;
float y= gl_FragCoord.y/screenheight;
float z= gl_FragCoord.z;
```

Comment: Just use the texture. What kind of "test" would you need?

Comment: @derhass I am using render to texture to create my texture. But when I use the texture I just get a black screen with no errors. I am positive render to texture is working correctly and the texture I want is being created So I am trying to see if the problem is texture coming in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to see the content of your texture, you could copy it to your default framebuffer using `glBlitFramebuffer`. Since you created it by using it as a render target, it's probably attached to an FBO already. Make that FBO your read framebuffer, set the draw framebuffer to the default framebuffer (both using `glBindFramebuffer`), and then call `glBlitFramebuffer` to copy it.

Myself, I would just use a minimal shader using the texture, and render. But the above is an alternative if you have problems with your shaders.

Is the code fragment you copied your entire fragment shader? It's missing a `main()` function, among other things.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No its not my complete shader it is just the part Where I was writing to test my texture. I do have my main. When you say minimal shader what do you mean?

Comment: By minimal shader, I mean a vertex shader that just passes through the position and texture coordinates (which can be generated from the same input attribute), and a fragment shader that samples the texture and writes the result to the output fragment color. Not counting declarations, that's two lines of code in the vertex shader, and one line in the fragment shader.